# In gremlin how to get specific properties based on another property

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

In gremlin I want to retrieve specific properties from a collection of vertices based on the property (an array which lists which properties in can have) of an adjacent property of their parents' vertex.
I am not sure if it even possible to do in one query.Below I have an example graph. There would actually be many Projects each Project has a single template (which has the list of allowed properties) and a collection of Documents. In the example below, because the Template connected to ProjectA only has property1 and property2 in the list I only want to get back property1 and property2 from the Documents.

```
g.addV('Project').property('name', 'ProjectA').as('p').
......1>    addV('Template').property('name','TemplateA').property(list,'allowed', 'property1').property(list,'allowed', 'property2').as('t').
......2>    addV('Document').property('name', 'DocumentA').property('property1', '1').property('property2', '2').property('property3', '3').as('d1').
......3>    addV('Document').property('name', 'DocumentB').property('property1', '1').property('property2', '2').property('property3', '3').as('d2').
......4>    addE('hasDocuments').from('p').to('d1').
......5>    addE('hasDocuments').from('p').to('d2').
......6>    addE('hasTemplate').from('p').to('t')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one query, by using aliasing and where filtering.

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   hasLabel('Project').as('project').
......2>   out('hasTemplate').
......3>   values('allowed').as('allowed_properties').
......4>   select('project').
......5>   out('hasDocuments').as('docs').
......6>   properties().as('selected_properties').
......7>   label().
......8>   where(eq('allowed_properties')).
......9>   select('selected_properties')
==>vp[property1->1]
==>vp[property1->1]
==>vp[property2->2]
==>vp[property2->2]
```

Comment: I always forget that `label()` works after `properties()`. It's probably worth mentioning that `key()` could also be used.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. It will take some Gremlin gymnastics:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name','ProjectA').
......1>   aggregate('p').by(out('hasTemplate').values('allowed').fold()).
......2>   out('hasDocuments').
......3>   elementMap().
......4>   map(unfold().as('kv').
......5>       filter(select('p').
......6>              unfold().unfold().as('p1').
......7>              where('p1',eq('kv')).
......8>                by().by(keys)).
......9>       group().by(keys).by(select(values)))
==>[property2:2,property1:1]
==>[property2:2,property1:1]
```

At line 1, we `aggregate()` the template keys to "p". Then we `elementMap()` all the documents which will grab all of their keys/values. We then start to filter each map at line 4 by `unfold()`-ing each one to its key/value pairs and then matching those keys against the ones in "p". We then use the common `group()` pattern on line 9 to merge the key/value pairs back into a `Map`.